# Test memory consumption

Tags: go

I need to verify how much memory a specific function consumes during execution, and make sure that it stays under a specific limit.

Ideally I'd like to do this in a test or benchmark. As far as I can see the only way to do this is to create a separate test binary and use the `BenchmarkResult` from

```
func Benchmark(f func(b *B)) BenchmarkResult
```

Is this the correct way to do this?

Comment: In GO std libs there is `testing.AllocsPerRun` but it allows to check only mallocs count

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually it's very simple:

1. Read memstats with `runtime.ReadMemStats(&m)` into `m`
2. Invoke `f()`
3. Read memstats again into `m2`
4. Calculate diff between `m` and `m2`

For example:

```
var m1, m2 runtime.MemStats
runtime.GC()
runtime.ReadMemStats(&m1)
f()
runtime.ReadMemStats(&m2)
fmt.Println("total:", m2.TotalAlloc - m1.TotalAlloc)
fmt.Println("mallocs:", m2.Mallocs - m1.Mallocs)
```

Comment: That is less simple than doing it the standard way.

Comment: Well, the standard way doesn't show me the information I want.

Comment: It shows you how many allocation operations were performed per invocation and how much memory was allocated during each invocation.  That seems to be what you stated you wanted.  Perhaps you could phrase your question better.

Comment: I have found this way to work for me. In creating a text editor I wanted to make sure that my implementation does not allocate strings left and right. I am checking that after 1000 operations I do not have 1000 times as much memory. For rough calculations like that, this is a good way to do it.
The important part is to call `runtime.GC()` at the start of your test function(s) that test the memory. Otherwise garbage from the other test functions is in there as well.

Comment: Thank you, this actually answers the question, and solves my problem. (I don't understand why people would think the other answer is the correct answer.)

Answer (score 21):

That's not really how you use the `testing` package.  Just create a file called `something_test.go` and write a function called `func BenchmarkSomething(b *testing.B)` and you're good to go.

The documentation of the [testing](http://golang.org/pkg/testing/) package goes into a lot more detail, but basically after you write your `_test.go` files, you just run them, enable benchmarks, and specific to your question, turn on `-benchmem`:

```
go test -bench=. -benchmem
```

That should give you what you're looking for.

Comment: Well the benchmark needs a setup phase where I generate sample data. So I guess that will show up in the benchmark as well, thus making it useless.

Comment: You can `ResetTimer()`, `StopTimer()`, `StartTimer()` using the methods on the [B type](http://golang.org/pkg/testing/#B)

Comment: The documentation I linked to directly addresses that concern and tells you what to do about it and shows an example of it being done.

Comment: @ErikAigner, wouldn't it be possible to generate your sample data in the `init()` function of your testing file?

Comment: @kostix -- you could do that, but it's not generally recommended.  Using the various Timer() functions illustrated above is the preferred solution.  On the one hand, it makes it visually explicit when reading the code what is and is not actually benchmarked, while on the other hand it frees up the source code layout to support multiple classes of test data for different test procedures.  You can do the latter with init() still, but again, it's ugly and not lexically obvious what's happening when reading the code.

Comment: This does not actually show how much memory a function uses/requires, nor how many memory allocations are being requested. (Unless there is some secret I don't know about)

Comment: Also these metrics are kind of pointless since you can't assert them.